# converting string cell value to seconds

Tags: c#, parsing

I have a data grid with column of time values like 0:15 , 0:30 , 0:45 , 1:00.

I want to colour backcolor to red when value of row.Cells[2] To string is higher than 1:00 so its 3600. I guess i need to convert it to seconds then check if its higer than searchValue. I managed to check if equal but I dont know how to convert it to seconds and then check if its higher.

```
        SqlDataAdapter asdf;
        DataTable ss;
        asdf = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Firma, Czas, Opis,ID FROM Rok2016 WHERE Dzien=@DT AND Kto=@Kto", con);
        asdf.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DT", monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Date);
        asdf.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kto", label3.Text);
        ss = new DataTable();

        asdf.Fill(ss);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ss;

        String searchValue = "3600";
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)



        if (row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))

            { 

                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `row.Cells[2].Value.ToString()` returns "00:15" or another number, like "01:14" or "15:53", then you can separate it into an array of hour and minute values, parse it to int (searchValueInSecondsString as well), convert it to a TimeSpan, get all the total seconds and final you can comparse it, like the following example:

```
String searchValueInSecondsString = "3600";

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    var separateHourAndMinutes = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Split(':');

    // safety first! ;)
    if (separateHourAndMinutes.Length != 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong time value from grid!");
    }
    else
    {
        // safety second! ;)
        if (int.TryParse(separateHourAndMinutes[0], out var hours) && int.TryParse(separateHourAndMinutes[1], out var minutes) && int.TryParse(searchValueInSecondsString, out var searchValue))
        {
            // if you want to make something red, if the search value and the time value are higher and equal, use >= instead of >
            if (new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, 0).TotalSeconds > searchValue)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I make it red!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice, that I have changed the name searchValue to searchValueInSecondsString, to know what input the search value needs (seconds and string)

P.S.: If you want to play a litte bit with that code click: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1OVfDy

Comment: row.Cells[2].Value.ToString() returns 00:15 00:30 etc i typed 3600 because I think i must somehow convert 00:15 to seconds and then compare it to hour

Comment: I have updated my answer. That should work for you. Additionally to the functionality, I have added some safety functions.